# Maven LifecycleExecutor getLifecycles() API Change

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am working on a plugin to make it compatible with maven 3 and one of the methods it uses is: LifecycleExecutor.getLifecycles() which is no longer part of the API for maven 3, but existed for maven 2. Is there a way around this to keep compatibility?

Here are the API's for reference:
http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/lifecycle/LifecycleExecutor.html

http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/lifecycle/LifecycleExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

As of Maven 3.1.1, this problem has been fixed.

Source:
http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-3-1-0-class-loading-error-with-Swagger-Maven-Plugin-td5763722.html